# How to Disable Vuetify v-application style(not theme)

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify.

I noticed that after integrating vuetify, it automatically sets class name v-application.

**However, that v-application has it's own style like p { margin-bottom: 16px; }.

And I want to disable all of it.**

I disabled theme but it didn't work.

Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using codesandbox to show the issue? That would help us to provide more insight into this issue.

Comment: Of course.  Give me a minute

Comment: so this would remove ALL vuetify's css styles .. is that what you want?

Comment: Not exactly. I already had complete css and then added vuetify with v-app tag. Then it automatically created class nane “v-application” and that added css to p and ul tags to whole application. I just want to keep original p and other styles I created. I will upload demo